# DbContext.Add changes an entity's property value

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

When I invoke the method `DbContext.Add`, a property value of my entity is changing and I don't know why:

I have this code (`context` is a field injected, derived from class `DbContext`):

```
    public async Task Add([FromBody] City item) {
        context.Add(item);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

This is the `City` class:

```
public class City {
    [Required]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int StateId { get; set; }
    public virtual State State { get; set; }
}
```

This is the `State` class:

```
public class State {
    [Required]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Before `context.Add(item)` runs, the values of entity item is `Text = "New York"` and `StateId = 1`. But when I step execute it, `StateId` is assigned to `0`. I have no idea why is this happening. Could you help me?

Comment: What is the key of class `City`?

Comment: It sounds like a mapping issue. What are the mappings, and did you set anything for the `State` property?

Comment: I forgot to add the key of `City` and just updated my question, and I also put the `State` class.
The mapping is `builder.Entity<City>().HasIndex(x => new { x.Text, x.StateId}).IsUnique();` and `builder.Entity<State>().HasIndex(x => x.Text).IsUnique();`

Comment: Does the `State` property of `City`contain any value when you adding entity to context?

Comment: Yes, it contains an initialized instance of `State`, with `Id = 0` and `Text = null` (default values).

Comment: @FelipeCostaGualberto `State` property must be `null` or valid entity tracked by DB context

Comment: That was the problem, thanks. If you answer, I'll mark it as the answer.